# python functools wraps when to use it and not to use it

Tags: python

I'm trying wrap my head around python decorators so I borrowed this supposedly fastest [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) [implementation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary/#Alternate_memoize_as_dict_subclass) :

```
class memoize(dict):
      def __init__(self, func):
          self.func = func
      def __call__(self, *args):
          return self[args]
      def __missing__(self, key):
          result = self[key] = self.func(*key)
          return result

>>> @memoize
... def foo(a, b):
...     return a * b
>>> foo(2, 4)
8
>>> foo
{(2, 4): 8}
```

Piece of cake but then I came to know about [functools wraps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps). The doc says it:

> This is a convenience function for invoking update_wrapper() as a function decorator when defining a wrapper function. It is equivalent to partial(update_wrapper, wrapped=wrapped, assigned=assigned, updated=updated).

When to use it and when not to use it ? Could anyone tell me If I've to use the above `class memoization` using that functools.wraps how would I change it ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do) already? Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357776/what-is-the-difference-between-functools-wraps-and-update-wrapper). Does it help answer your question?

Comment: you should probably use functools.lru_cache in the first place

Comment: @idjaw Then the right way of doing a decorator is using wraps ?